# Redshift/SQL: check if how many words in string1 existent in string2

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to solve the following within Redshift:

If I have this dataset:

```
string 1      string 2           
red shift     red pencil has to shift
red shift     red flowers are nice
```

I'd like to find exact # of words that appear in both strings, i.e. for the first row above it would be 2 and for the second -- 1.

I understand how to do it in Python or Excel, but the data is in SQL. Any ideas how to tackle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split both strings into words using `SPLIT_PART()` - into two in-line tables, while keeping the original strings in them.

Then join the two in-line tables on an equi join on the two original strings, the words you split them into, and count.

Mind you, you would be much more efficient with an Integer based primary key, so you would only  have to carry the primary key along for the GROUP BY part - much more efficient to group by one integer than two strings of possibly cumbersome length - joining back over the integer primary key to get back the original strings.

Here goes:

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(s1,s2) AS (
          SELECT 'red shift','red pencil has to shift'
UNION ALL SELECT 'red shift','red flowers are nice'
)
,
-- real query starts here - replace comma above with "WITH" ...
-- need a series of integers ...
i(i) AS (
          SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4
UNION ALL SELECT 5
UNION ALL SELECT 6
UNION ALL SELECT 7
UNION ALL SELECT 8
)
,
-- split s1 into words ...
s1_parts AS (
  SELECT
    s1
  , s2
  , i
  , SPLIT_PART(s1,' ',i) AS wrd
FROM indata CROSS JOIN i
WHERE SPLIT_PART(s1,' ',i) <> ''
)
,
-- split s2 into words ...
s2_parts AS (
  SELECT
    s1
  , s2
  , i
  , SPLIT_PART(s2,' ',i) AS wrd
FROM indata CROSS JOIN i
WHERE SPLIT_PART(s2,' ',i) <> ''
)
-- << content of s2_parts for documentation ... >>
-- out     s1     |           s2            | i |   wrd   
-- out -----------+-------------------------+---+---------
-- out  red shift | red pencil has to shift | 1 | red
-- out  red shift | red pencil has to shift | 2 | pencil
-- out  red shift | red pencil has to shift | 3 | has
-- out  red shift | red pencil has to shift | 4 | to
-- out  red shift | red pencil has to shift | 5 | shift
-- out  red shift | red flowers are nice    | 1 | red
-- out  red shift | red flowers are nice    | 2 | flowers
-- out  red shift | red flowers are nice    | 3 | are
-- out  red shift | red flowers are nice    | 4 | nice

-- join the two word splitted in-line tables on equal words ...
SELECT
  s1_parts.s1
, s1_parts.s2
, COUNT(*) AS matching_words
FROM s1_parts JOIN s2_parts USING(s1,s2,wrd)
GROUP BY
  s1_parts.s1
, s1_parts.s2
;
-- out     s1     |           s2            | matching_words 
-- out -----------+-------------------------+----------------
-- out  red shift | red flowers are nice    |              1
-- out  red shift | red pencil has to shift |              2
```